# Refactoring Jquery: parsing json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I use the following code for two links: a.vote-down-0 and a.vote-up-0, they do the same thing, except each one specifies whether the vote is up or down.

```
$('a.vote-down-0').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).siblings('.reply-id').val();
    var ajax_auth_token = $('#auth_token').val();
    var c_button = this;


    $.post('user/?action=ajax', {
        vote_type: 'down',
        reply_id: id,
        auth_token: ajax_auth_token
    }, function(data, return_status) {   //return status is just if ajax works or not

        var json_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        switch(json_data.r_message)
        {
           case "success": 
              output = "Yay it works!"; // change 
              $(c_button).removeClass('vote-down-0').addClass('vote-down-1');
              $(c_button).siblings('a.vote-up-0').addClass('vote-up-1').removeClass('vote-up-0'); // ** TODO: this needs to be repeated for all cases below**
           break;

           case "no_vote":
              output = "You've run  out of negative votes.";
           break;

           case "vote_limit":
              output = "You can vote anymore today. Limit is 25 per day.";
           break;

           case "login": 
              output= "You need to login before you can vote.";
           break;

           case "own":
              output = "You cannot vote on your own comment.";
              $(c_button).removeClass('vote-down-0').addClass('vote-down-1');

           break;

           case "already":
              output ="You have already voted on this.";
           break;

           case "session":
              output = "Your login session has expired, please login again.";
           break;

    }

alert(output);
```

This reads the response send back via Json and gives a different alert for each case.

Is there an easier way of doing this? How could this be re-factored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the class of your a tags from

```
<a class="vote-up-0">
```

to

```
<a class="vote-0 up">
```

you could then refactor the two functions as:

```
$('a.vote-0').click(function() {
    var voteType =  $(this).is('.up') ? 'up' : 'down';

    ... snip ...

    $.post('user/?action=ajax', {
        vote_type: voteType,
        reply_id: id,
        auth_token: ajax_auth_token
    }
    ...
```

The code for `case success` then simply becomes:

```
$(c_button).removeClass('vote-0').addClass('vote-1');
$(c_button).siblings('a.vote-0').addClass('vote-1').removeClass('vote-0');
```